# LLVM MinGW installation on Vista?

Tags: installation, mingw, windows-vista, llvm, llvm-gcc

From [llvm.org](http://llvm.org/) I've downloaded llvm-2.6-x86-mingw32.tar.bz2 into `c:\llvm` and llvm-gcc-4.2-2.6-x86-mingw32-tar.bz2 into `c:\llvm-gcc` as well as setup a desktop shortcut the following batch file in `c:\llvm-gcc` which attempts to setup an environment for compiling via the `llvm-gcc` command line too:

```
@echo off
color 0E
echo Configuring LLVM environment...
set LLVM_LIB_SEARCH_PATH=%~dp0lib
set PATH=c:\llvm;%~dp0bin;%PATH%
```

Unfortunately, this setup gives the following error when trying to compile a simple hello world program:

```
C:\CDev\sandbox>llvm-gcc -o hello.exe hello.c
llvm-gcc: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
```

I've briefly looked through the LLVM binaries and it appears that the MinGW-based Win32 API and runtime files are already included.  I also tried adding the MinGW DLL to `c:\llvm-gcc\bin` to no avail.

What have I missed in setting up the binary LLVM environment and GCC-based front end on Vista?

Thanks, Jon

Answer (score 3):

Because the GNU/MinGW assembler 'as' was required by 'llvm-gcc' to generate the obj file. The problem can be solved by using:

1. Install GNU/MinGW [binutils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/GNU%20Binutils/binutils-2.20/binutils-2.20-1-mingw32-bin.tar.gz/download), extract the as.exe into c:\llvm-gcc\bin
2. Install a full MinGW package, add %MinGW%\bin your %PATH%

Answer (score 2):

@rwallace is correct that one needs to also install MinGW's binutils along with the LLVM binary download. I've updated the LLVM documentation appropriately at

http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#installcf

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the answer is that the MinGW distribution supplied by LLVM is not complete, in particular, it doesn't come with the 'binutils' programs.

The recommended solution seems to be to download and install MinGW yourself. However, the MinGW download page seems to be saying this requires 10 different packages to be downloaded and installed separately.

The solution I tried today was to use the MinGW that comes with Qt, which does come in a single package; thus far, that appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is looking for the base MinGW installation in C:\MinGW. I just had this error today using gcc.exe in msys. To solve it, I created a symbolic link from c:\msys to c:\MinGW and everything worked.