# Gcc.exe: CreateProcess : No such File or directory - Error?

Tags: file, directory, createprocess

I am writing an Objective C program and i saved it as 'hello.m'. The problem is when i am trying to compile it usig MinGW it is giving an error

**gcc hello.m** // i used for compiling 
and it is giving following error

**gcc.exe: CreateProcess : No such File or directory**

is there any way to fix ..so that i can move forward..

Thank You

Comment: I progressed a bit further by running gcc with the -v option/(verbose) - this told me that it was looking for as.exe, but not finding it.  This seems to be related to binutils/llvm - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816469/llvm-mingw-installation-on-vista

Answer (score 2):

Use Sysinternals ProcessMonitor from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). What you do is find the .exe name that is doing the compiling under the Process Name column, like `gcc.exe`. Then look in the Result column and anything that is not a `SUCCESS` check it out. I think what you are looking for is a `NAME NOT FOUND` result though. Also, I noticed that when I ran it from a shell, like msys, it didn't show up properly. So make sure to run the gcc compile from the command prompt.

I had this same problem and did what I just mentioned above, I found that `gcc.exe` was getting a `NAME NOT FOUND` result for `cc1obj.exe`. So I made an educated guess and went into my MinGW folder under `\libexec\gcc\mingw32\4.5.0` (the version number might not be the same for you) and made a copy of `cc1.exe` then renamed it as `cc1obj.exe`. And wala, that fixed the problem.